# Counting the instances of a variable that exceeds a threshold

Tags: r, count, grouping

I have a dataset with id and speed.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)

speed <- c(40,30,50,40,45,50,30,55,50,50,60)

i <- cbind(id, speed)

limit <- 35
```

Say, if 'speed' crosses 'limit' will count it as 1. And you will count again only if speed comes below and crosses the 'limit'.

I want data to be like.

```
 id | Speed Viol.
 ----------
 1  |   2
 ---------
 2  |   2
 ---------
 3  |   1
 ---------
```

here id (count).

```
 id1 (1) 40 (2) 50,40

 id2 (1) 45,50 (2) 55

 id3 (1) 50,50,60
```

How to do it not using `if()`.

Comment: Have you tried `tapply`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method `tapply` as suggested in the comments and the original vectors.

```
tapply(speed, id, FUN=function(x) sum(c(x[1] > limit, diff(x > limit)) > 0))
1 2 3 
2 2 1
```

`tapply` applies a function to each group, here, by ID. The function checks if the first element of an ID is over 35, and then concatenates this to the output of `diff`, whose argument is checking if subsequent observations are greater than 35. Thus `diff` checks if an ID returns to above 35 after dropping below that level. Negative values in the resulting vector are converted to FALSE (0) with `> 0` and these results are summed.

`tapply` returns a named vector, which can be fairly nice to work with. However, if you want a data.frame, then you could use `aggregate` instead as suggested by d.b:

```
aggregate(speed, list(id=id), FUN=function(x) sum(c(x[1] > limit, diff(x > limit)) > 0))
  id x
1  1 2
2  2 2
3  3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. I group by `id` then check if speed is above the limit in each row, but wasn't in the previous entry. (I get the previous row using `lag`). If this is the case, it produces `TRUE`. Or, if it's the first row for the `id` (i.e., `row_number()==1`) and it's above the limit, this gives a `TRUE`, too. Then, I sum all the `TRUE` values for each `id` using `summarise`.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)   
speed <- c(40,30,50,40,45,50,30,55,50,50,60)
i <- data.frame(id, speed)
limit <- 35

library(dplyr)

i %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(viol=(speed>limit&lag(speed)<limit)|(row_number()==1&speed>limit)) %>% 
  summarise(sum(viol))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id `sum(viol)`
  <dbl>       <int>
1     1           2
2     2           2
3     3           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(i)[, id1 := rleid(speed > limit), by = id][
          speed > limit, .(violations = uniqueN(id1)), by = id][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    id violations
> 1:  1          2
> 2:  2          2
> 3:  3          1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(speed~id, data.frame(i), function(x) sum(rle(x>limit)$values))
#  id speed
#1  1     2
#2  2     2
#3  3     1
```

The main idea is that `x > limit` will check for instances when the speed limit is violated and `rle(x)` will group those instances into consecutive violations or consecutive non-violations. Then all you need to do is to count the groups of consecutive violations (when `rle(x>limit)$values` is `TRUE`).